# What happens when a process puts a lock on a resource, and then aborts without releasing that resource?

Tags: c++, winapi, process, resources, locks

The abort function "bypasses the normal destruction process for initialized global static variables" per MS C++ Docs.  What happens when a process aborts or objects are otherwise not properly destroyed and the implied resource de-acquisition is not performed?

For example, how would a file lock be cleared?  Does the OS keep track of all the resources a process acquires, or would each file in the fs have to be queried?  What would happen if a process puts a lock on stdin?  The user would have no way of interacting with the system.

Comment: OS-level lock should be unlocked by the OS when the process exits.

Comment: This the process is aborted, and is gone, there's nothing left, to care about anything.

Comment: it is worse: ["Destructors of variables with automatic, thread local (since C++11) and static storage durations are not called."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort) if only globals  would be affected it wouldnt be such a big deal.

Comment: The OS cleans up (in most cases - SysV shared memory is a notable exception).  That's generally what happens when your process terminates. The OS cleans up and releases any acquired resources. Think about what would happen to a memory leaking process if the OS did not clean up when it terminated - then that leak would be a OS level problem rather than just a process problem (while running).

Comment: It literally means that: Acquired resources aren't being released. The consequences depend on the specific resource: Kernel objects have their reference count decremented, memory is released, and GDI/USER32 resources are freed as the process object is being destroyed (which happens when the last handle to it is closed). Everything else is pretty much left as it was: Servers, for example, that require explicit calls to free server-side resources won't know that the client terminated.

Comment: Anyway, we should avoid the behavior. The best way to overcome is releasing resources before the process terminated.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT That's just a blanket statement without any nuance. The best way is to understand the consequences, and choose judiciously. There are valid reasons to *not* release resources. Cleaning up lots and lots of heap memory, one allocation at a time, can easily add up to seconds or even minutes for a "clean" shutdown. Leaving that cleanup to the OS that can release the same memory in one fell swoop can significantly speed up shutdown, without any adverse effects.